# How to get currently displayed month and year in format "MM/yyyy" in JTCalendar Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, jtcalendar

I want to get the currently displayed month with year in the format "MM/yyyy" eg. 03/2017 in `JTCalendar`.

Here is my code which is called in a method `getCurrentMonthAndYear`

```
NSDateFormatter *monthYearFormatter;

[_calendarManager reload];

if (!monthYearFormatter) {
    monthYearFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    monthYearFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/yyyy";
}

NSString *monthYear = [monthYearFormatter stringFromDate:[_calendarManager date]];
```

Not sure about `[_calendar date]` because this method doesn't return exact month and year displayed in `JTCalendar` when navigating from one month to another.

I've also tried

`- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareMenuItemView:(UIView *)menuItemView date:(NSDate *)date` 
method, there i was getting 3 months, one previous and one after the month which is displayed.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit 2:

Tried calling the `getCurrentMonthAndYear` method inside `- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareMenuItemView:(UIView *)menuItemView date:(NSDate *)date`. This however returns the exact month and year which is being viewed, but the method is called 3 times. So this hits my API 3 times.

Comment: Do you want to get date to be returned in "MM/yyyy" eg. 03/2017 format?

Comment: @iCoderzDevelopers Yes ofcourse. I've already mentioned.

Comment: Can you try updating format as per answer?

Comment: @iCoderzDevelopers Yes i've tried that already.

Comment: @iCoderzDevelopers Please read the question, Edit 2. Formatting is not the issue. I'm not able to get the correct month and year. In Edit 2, i'm getting what i want but the method is called 3 times.

Comment: ok so you want to retrieve current calendar date when switching months?

Comment: @iCoderzDevelopers Yes exactly. Suppose user opens JTCalender today, they will get NSString 03/2017. If they move back one month they should get 02/2017. I have two buttons for navigating the months and have called methods `[_calendarContentView loadPreviousPageWithAnimation]` and `[_calendarContentView loadNextPageWithAnimation]` on these buttons.

Comment: Ok did you implemented delegate event "calendarDidLoadPreviousPage"?

Comment: @iCoderzDevelopers Okay! I guess that will do the trick. I'll try and report.

Comment: I just updated answer. You can try and let me know if it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated code:

- (void)calendarDidLoadPreviousPage
  {

  [self getCurrentMonthAndYear];

  NSLog(@"Prev Date: %@", self.calendar.currentDate);
  }

Let me know if it is working.

Comment: There is no object `calendar`. But i've found a workaround. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you use "calendarDidLoadPreviousPage" delegate method?

Comment: Yes. `calendarDidLoadPreviousPage` and `calendarDidLoadNextPage`. There i called my `getCurrentMonthAndYear` method followed by `loadDataFromServer`. This manages to call the API one time only.

Comment: Can't upvote yet because of lower reputation. However accepted your answer as that delegate method helped. Please add my workaround also, so that people can know. Thanks again